# XSLT Print Checks

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT 1.0. My XML File looks something like this

```
<Results>
  <comment>Test 1</comment>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed/Result>
  </Action>

  <comment>Test 2</comment>
  <Action>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Action>

  <comment>Test 3</comment>
  <Action>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Failed</Result>
  </Action>

  <comment>Test 4</comment>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Action>
  <Action>
    <Result>Passed</Result>
  </Action>      
</Results>
```

How do I get it to print out a Failed if the test case failed, but only do it once per test case. I was able to use for-each to get it to print off a failed each time. The way I did it, it would print off a ton of fails for some cases, but I don't want to look at 10+ lines that just say failed. I tried using count and number, but I haven't come up with anything that seemed like it would actually work.

My code looks like

```
<xsl:for-each select="Results">
    <xsl:for-each select="Action[Result='Failed']">
        <tr title = "binit">
            <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">Failed </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

How do I get it to print

```
Test 1
Test 2
Failed
Test 3
Failed
Test 4
```

instead of

```
Test 1
Test 2
Failed
Failed
Test 3
Failed
Failed 
Test 4
```

The html should look something like

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Failed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test 3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Failed</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Test 4</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="actions" match="Action" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::comment[1])" />

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="comment">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <xsl:if test="key('actions', generate-id())[Result='Failed']">
                 <tr>
                    <td>Failed</td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I think my question was poorly phrased. I added more information to it that might make my problem a bit clearer.

Comment: See my edited answer. If this does not answer your question, please post a **reproducible** example, including a **complete** stylesheet and the expected output **as code**.

Comment: When I try to apply this solution, it prints off the first Failed, but if there is a test afterwards that fails, it doesn't print a failed for that test. Is there a way to reset it or something along those lines?

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted: "*to print out a Failed if the test case failed, but only do it once*"?

Comment: Yes that is what I wanted. The problem is let's say Test 2 fails, it prints out Failed because it's the first failed that it finds. However, if there are failed actions under the comment Test 3, it does not print a Failed.

Comment: Please edit your question sas I asked earlier. Include an input with **all** possible scenarios and the expected output **as code**. Also, since it now turns out this is a grouping question, state if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I updated it, but I don't know what you mean by output as code. Do you mean the actual html that it would produce?

Comment: "*Do you mean the actual html that it would produce?*" Yes.

Comment: I made the changes that you wanted. The output should really be rather simple. I'm using XSLT 1.0 as stated above. If you can help/know what to do, that'd be aweseome, but if not that's fine too.

Comment: @Dschmied Try it now.

Comment: It worked on the small example that I have, but when I tried to apply it to my much larger actual file, it didn't quite work. In the real xml, there's 100+ tests with 20-30 actions each which is why the example I have is just a small version of that. But why did this solution partially work? In my real Test 1, there are 5 Faileds and it printed off 1 Failed. In my real Test 3 it has 11 Failed, and it printed off 5. If there are comments that aren't just the Test #, could that confuse this code?

Comment: Apparently, your real input is somehow different from the example. Since I cannot see it, I have no way of telling how.

Comment: I'm sorry. Can you explain to me what this is doing? When I strip everything except for the comments with the Test and the Action with the result, it is working perfectly. But when I have the entire xml with all the extra stuff it prints out extra Failed lines sometimes. What is your code doing?

Comment: First, it binds all Actions to the first comment that precedes them (that's what `xsl:key`does). Then it processes all comments, and looks at the group of actions that are bound to it to see if any of these have a Result ="Failed". -- Is it possible you have comments of another kind?

Comment: So I need the key to bind to specific comments instead of all the comments. For example, here I would want to bind to all comments that start with Test or something like that.

Comment: @Dschmied Probably. I cannot comment without seeing your input. And this is getting too long.

Comment: I know sorry. I'll figure that part out myself, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about this..  I need to frame a question in here to get the formatting..

I suspect the answer is going to be some ugly xslt becuase of the structure of the xml input does not lend itself well to the problem:  Are you able to alter the input xml to one of these two options:

```
<Results>
  <comment>Test 1</comment>
  <Actions>
    <Action>
     <Result>Passed</Result>
    </Action>
    <Action>
     <Result>Passed/Result>
    </Action>
  </Actions>
 ...
</Results>
```

or

```
<Results>
   <Test>
     <comment>Test 1</comment>
     <Action>
        <Result>Passed</Result>
      </Action>
      <Action>
        <Result>Passed/Result>
      </Action>
  </Test>
 ...
</Results>
```

Comment: I cannot alter the input xml, which is why I'm stuck.